# Catch-all for if-else in C

Tags: c, if-statement, keyword

We all know that C has `if` statements, and parts of that family are the `else if` and `else` statements. The `else` by itself checks if none of the values succeeded, and if so, runs the proceeding code.

I was wondering if there's something like the opposite of an `else` that checks if *all* of the values succeeded instead of *none* of them.

Let's say I have this code:

```
if (someBool)
{
    someBit &= 3;
    someFunction();
}
else if (someOtherBool)
{
    someBit |= 3;
    someFunction();
}
else if (anotherBool)
{
    someBit ^= 3;
    someFunction();
}
else
{
    someOtherFunction();
}
```

Sure, I could shorten this with:

- a `goto` (gee, wonder why I won't do that)
- writing `if (someBool || someOtherBool || anotherBool)` (messy and not remotely portable).

I figured it'd be much easier to write something like this:

```
if (someBool)
    someBit &= 3;
else if (someOtherBool)
    someBit |= 3;
else if (anotherBool)
    someBit ^= 3;
all  // if all values succeed, run someFunction
    someFunction();
else
    someOtherFunction();
```

Does C have this capability?

Comment: **No** it does not.

Comment: This wouldn't work since once one condition is true, it doesn't even check the rest. This would require forcing it to check all conditions regardless which could potentially kill performance. Higher level languages, like Python, have an `all` function for this purpose (although it works differently than you propose).

Comment: Another thing to note is that a decent compiler will produce the machine equivalent of the `goto` solution you mention. I.e., there will be only one call (or one inlined version) of  `someFunction` in the compiled code. So brevity at the source level would be the only advantage of a feature like this, if it didn't have the short circuit problem that @Carcigenicate described.

Comment: Technically you are looking for `&&`, not `||` and it's not especially messy.

Comment: Would the C Switch statement be cleaner?  Then you can have a default.

Comment: `goto` is acceptable in C.

Comment: @GovindParmar Any code with a a `goto` in C gets made fun of forever.

Comment: The Linux kernel uses gotos, so do a lot of code samples on MSDN

Comment: @GovindParmar All I'm saying is, `goto`s are a bit of a joke in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done with using an additional variable. For example

```
int passed = 0;

if (passed = someBool)
{
    someBit &= 3;
}
else if (passed = someOtherBool)
{
    someBit |= 3;
}
else if (passed = anotherBool)
{
    someBit ^= 3;
}

if (passed)
{
    someFunction();
}
else
{
    someOtherFunction();
}
```

To stop GCC from showing `warning: suggest parenthesis around assignment value`, write each  `(passed = etc)` as `((passed = etc))`.

Comment: Oh, not bad! Any way to do this that doesn't make GCC shout at you?

Comment: @Redesign AFAIK you need to enclose the assignment in parentheses inside the if statement. For example if ( ( pass = expression ) )

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but I add my own version either.

```
return
someBool?      (someBit &= 3, someFunction()) :
someOtherBool? (someBit |= 3, someFunction()) :
anotherBool?   (someBit ^= 3, someFunction()) :
someOtherFunction();
```

or like that

```
(void(*)(void)
someBool?      (someBit &= 3, someFunction) :
someOtherBool? (someBit |= 3, someFunction) :
anotherBool?   (someBit ^= 3, someFunction) :
someOtherFunction
)();
```

or like that

```
void (*continuation)(void) =
someBool?      (someBit &= 3, someFunction) :
someOtherBool? (someBit |= 3, someFunction) :
anotherBool?   (someBit ^= 3, someFunction) :
someOtherFunction;
continuation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int test=0;

if (someBool) {
    test++;
    someBit &= 3;
    someFunction();
}

if (someOtherBool) {
    test++;
    someBit |= 3;
    someFunction();
}

if (anotherBool) {
    test++;
    someBit ^= 3;
    someFunction();
}

if (test==0) {
    noneFunction();
} else if (test==3) {
    allFunction();
}
```